# Meteor server restart time

Tags: meteor

I'm on Meteor version 1.2.1. Whenever Meteor detects a change to backend code it restarts the server. You'll see a spinning character in the console, maybe some other messages depending on what packages you have installed and then:

```
=> Meteor server restarted
```

It takes around 7 seconds on my 4-year-old Macbook Pro.

I started working on an existing app which has around 20 JavaScript files and around 20 third-party packages installed (see package list below). It takes 30sec to restart the server after any change to server-side code.

Before I go digging in seeing what I can remove to speed things up I wanted to ask if these numbers (7 sec for an empty app and 30sec for a moderate sized app) seem normal, is this roughly what other meteor developers are experiencing or do I have something weird going on?

Does anyone have an idea of the the impact a new computer would have on build times?

Any tips for troubleshooting? Should I experiment with removing packages first or are there other aspects of my setup that are likely to have a bigger impact?

Thanks!

```
    $ meteor list
    angular                                        1.2.2  Everything you need to use AngularJS in your Meteor app
    angular:angular-messages                       1.4.7  AngularJS (official) release. For full solution: http://angular-meteor.com/
    angular:angular-mocks                          1.4.7  AngularJS (official) release. For full solution: http://angular-meteor.com/
    angularui:angular-ui-router                    0.2.15  angular-ui-router (official): Flexible routing with nested views in Angu...
    check                                          1.1.0  Check whether a value matches a pattern
    chrismbeckett:toastr                           2.1.2_1  Gnome / Growl type non-blocking notifications
    coffeescript                                   1.0.11  Javascript dialect with fewer braces and semicolons
    cordova:com.ionic.keyboard                     1.0.4
    cordova:com.plugin.datepicker                  https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker.git#1e0f4bf47b0c343...
    cordova:uk.co.whiteoctober.cordova.appversion  https://github.com/whiteoctober/cordova-plugin-app-version.git#22e8147c51a168c0c...
    driftyco:ionic                                 1.1.0_2  Ionic Framework official Meteor package
    ejson                                          1.0.7  Extended and Extensible JSON library
    fourseven:scss                                 3.2.0* Style with attitude. Sass and SCSS support for Meteor.js (with autoprefix...
    ground:db                                      0.3.14  Ground Meteor.Collections offline
    http                                           1.1.1  Make HTTP calls to remote servers
    jquery                                         1.11.4  Manipulate the DOM using CSS selectors
    logging                                        1.0.8  Logging facility.
    matb33:collection-hooks                        0.8.1  Extends Mongo.Collection with before/after hooks for insert/update/remove...
    meteor-base                                    1.0.1  Packages that every Meteor app needs
    meteoric:ionic-sass                            0.3.0  Ionic's CSS Framework in SASS and bundled for Meteor.
    mobile-experience                              1.0.1  Packages for a great mobile user experience
    mongo                                          1.1.3  Adaptor for using MongoDB and Minimongo over DDP
    netanelgilad:ng-cordova                        0.1.13  AngularJS Cordova wrappers for common Cordova plugins.
    random                                         1.0.5  Random number generator and utilities
    reload                                         1.1.4  Reload the page while preserving application state.
    sanjo:jasmine                                  0.20.2  Velocity integration of the Jasmine testing framework
    session                                        1.1.1  Session variable
    spacebars                                      1.0.7  Handlebars-like template language for Meteor
    standard-minifiers                             1.0.2  Standard minifiers used with Meteor apps by default.
    stevezhu:lodash                                3.10.1  A utility library delivering consistency, customization, performance, & ...
    tracker                                        1.0.9  Dependency tracker to allow reactive callbacks
    velocity:html-reporter                         0.9.1  Reactive Velocity test reports in your app.
```

Comment: this is a particular problem with v1.2. hopefully to be fixed soon. https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/5269